# How do I get an object from d3.data()?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a variable holding all my links data in a force directed graph

```
var linkData = d3.selectAll(".link").data();
```

I have a for loop looping through this data to see if any of the edges have a certain value. 
If they have I wish to change the class of that edge to visible, if not then change it to hidden.

But the thing I am confused with is say I get the edge I want at `linkData[3];` how do I chose the actual link so I can change the CSS class, seen as the linkData is the data, how do I get the actual object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`filter` a selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter):

```
var myLink = d3.selectAll(".link")
             .filter(function(d) { return d === linkData[3]; })
             .attr('stroke', 'red');
```

---

Or, better still, as LeartS suggested, you can directly filter the link without whisking through the `.data()` from the DOM:

```
var myLink = d3.selectAll(".link")
             .filter(function(d) { return isThisTheLinkIWant(d); })
             .attr('stroke', 'red');
```

Comment: He can use the `filter` function to directly search the data and yet still operate on the selection, I would explain that instead of showing `d === linkData[3]`. i.e. there is no need to determine linkData[3] (or any other 'valid' data) before.